# Generating Unique ID for phone (without using UDID)

Tags: javascript, cordova, udid

I need to generate a unique ID for phones (to be able to identify the user) but do not want to use the UDID due to the lack of future support (in Iphone 5, etc). I am using Phonegap for my applications. Is there a good way to generate "random" ID based on phone name / hardware / etc? 
I believe there is a JS function that could do something like this but I am not sure and hence seek clarification.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Someone has released a UUID alternative which you could use in iOS5 (linked below) which generates a token based on the Mac Address. You could make use of the Plugin System in Phonegap to run this Objective-C Code and then return the new token in to your Javascript Code

Github Project - UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5: https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5

**Edit**: For other devices such as Blackberry and Android, you could just use the `device.uuid` call available in Phonegap. This is explained in the [Device Section of the PhoneGap Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_device_device.md.html)

Comment: Thanks! What about Blackberry though?

Comment: Added an Edit to answer for Blackberry and Android and other devices :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create unique and random string using `CFUUIDCreate` function which will be very much random.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has something called CFUDID (or similar to that, can't remember the exact name) that will generate a unique ID based on a few different factors. I would check out the documentation for that.